How can I fit a `HoltWinters` model with the `fable` package?
I have a tsibble with data every 15 minutes.

I want to simulate:
ts_data <- ts(data$value, deltat = 1/96) # There is a daily seasonality
model <- HoltWinters(ts_data)
predictions <- predict(model , n.ahead = 96)

How can I do this using fable? I have trouble adding the deltat/frequency parameter somewhere.
I tried:
data_train |> 
  model(hw = ETS(consumption ~ trend("A") + season("A"))) |> 
  forecast(h = 96) 

The first model is able to show seasonal predictions (accurate) but the one inside model cannot at all, at stays around the same value.
 hw_failed   predictions
        <num>    <num>
 1:  169.6353 147.8264
 2:  170.0528 146.8748
 3:  169.4447 144.4163
 4:  168.9828 148.3482
 5:  169.1216 150.3192
 6:  169.5391 148.2540
 7:  168.9311 140.0981
 8:  168.4691 139.4991
 9:  168.6079 139.5674
10:  169.0254 142.2911
11:  168.4174 142.9221
12:  167.9554 139.7753
13:  168.0942 137.0976
14:  168.5117 132.5767
15:  167.9037 127.5558
16:  167.4417 129.5384
17:  167.5806 132.2143
18:  167.9981 129.2312
19:  167.3900 127.7812
20:  166.9280 125.2476
21:  167.0669 128.3527
22:  167.4844 129.4398
23:  166.8763 129.7902
24:  166.4143 128.3030
25:  166.5532 131.6526
26:  166.9707 134.2288
27:  166.3626 145.7738
28:  165.9007 143.3738
29:  166.0395 146.6691
30:  166.4570 143.6985
31:  165.8489 135.0897
32:  165.3870 136.5083
33:  165.5258 141.6454
34:  165.9433 219.8764
35:  165.3353 219.7798
36:  164.8733 219.1824


The ETS function will use the smallest possible seasonal period by default. Here you have 15-minute data, so it will use seasonal period of 4 (i.e., modelling hourly seasonality which probably doesn't exist). If you want some other seasonal period, you need to specify it explicitly in the season() call. e.g.,
data_train |> 
  model(hw = ETS(consumption ~ trend("A") + season("A", period = "day"))) |> 
  forecast(h = 96) 
#> Warning: 1 error encountered for hw
#> [1] Seasonal periods (`period`) of length greather than 24 are not supported by ETS.

But as you can see from the error message, ETS will not allow seasonal periods of greater than 24 because that would require 23 parameters to estimate the seasonality. Here you have a seasonal period of 96.
The HoltWinters function uses a rough heuristic estimate of the seasonal component which will be computed for any seasonal period, but which is almost certainly very poor in this case.
You would be better off using a different model such as TBATS or ARIMA with Fourier terms for the seasonality.

Thank you Rob!
I'm following your book to learn. Code is great, clean and the explanations easy to follow.
Just to be sure, there would not be an equivalent to the HoltWinters function in fable? (At least for my seasonal period > 24)

No, we won't be adding that to fable.
